# Statistical probability of N contiguous true-bits in a sequence of bits?

Tags: math, statistics, probability, bit

Let's assume I have an N-bit stream of generated bits. (In my case 64kilobits.)

Whats the probability of finding a sequence of X "all true" bits, contained within a stream of N bits. Where X = (2 to 16), and N = (16 to 1000000), and X < N.

For example:
If N=16 and X=5, whats the likelyhood of finding 11111 within a 16-bit number.

Like this pseudo-code:

```
int N = 1<<16; // (64KB)
int X = 5;
int Count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int ThisCount = ContiguousBitsDiscovered(i, X);
    Count += ThisCount;
}
return Count;
```

That is, if we ran an integer in a loop from 0 to 64K-1... how many times would 11111 appear within those numbers.

Extra rule: 1111110000000000 doesn't count, because it has 6 true values in a row, not 5. So:

```
1111110000000000 = 0x // because its 6 contiguous true bits, not 5.
1111100000000000 = 1x
0111110000000000 = 1x
0011111000000000 = 1x
1111101111100000 = 2x
```

I'm trying to do some work involving physically-based random-number generation, and detecting "how random" the numbers are. Thats what this is for.

...

This would be easy to solve if N were less than 32 or so, I could just "run a loop" from 0 to 4GB, then count how many contiguous bits were detected once the loop was completed. Then I could store the number and use it later.

Considering that X ranges from 2 to 16, I'd literally only need to store 15 numbers, each less than 32 bits! (if N=32)!

BUT in my case N = 65,536. So I'd need to run a loop, for 2^65,536 iterations. Basically impossible :)

No way to "experimentally calculate the values for a given X, if N = 65,536". So I need maths, basically.

Comment: Model it exactly as a fair coin.  True/false bits ~ heads/tails on a fair coin.  Standard statistical treatment can tell you how likely it is that you can get N consecutive heads or tails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix `X` and `N`, obiously with `X < N`. You have `2^N` possible values of combinations of 0 and 1 in your bit number, and you have `N-X +1` possible sequences of `1*X` (in this part I'm only looking for `1's` together) contained in you bit number. Consider for example `N = 5` and `X = 2`, this is a possible valid bit number `01011`, so fixed the last two characteres (the last two `1's`) you have `2^2` possible combinations for that `1*X`sequence. Then you have two cases:

**Border case**: Your `1*X` is in the border, then you have `(2^(N -X -1))*2` possible combinations

**Inner case**: You have `(2^(N -X -2))*(N-X-1)` possible combinations.

So, the probability is `(border + inner )/2^N`

Examples:

- 1)`N = 3, X =2`, then the proability is `2/2^3`
- 2) `N = 4, X = 2`, then the probaility is  `5/16`

Comment: it's very important to say that, we are assuming that your number generation process is an independent process and the proability to get `1` is `0.5` (Bernoulli distribution) :D

Comment: I hate maffs but this is really good. If only I could understand how you did dis... Id learn how 2 maff properly...

Answer (score 1):

A bit brute force, but I'd do something like this to avoid getting mired in statistics theory:

- Multiply the probabilities (1 bit = 0.5, 2 bits = 0.5*0.5, etc) while looping
- Keep track of each X and when you have the product of X bits, flip it and continue
- Start with small example (N = 5, X=1 - 5) to make sure you get edge cases right, compare to brute force approach.

This can probably be expressed as something like Sum (Sum 0.5^x (x = 1 -> 16) (for n = 1 - 65536) , but edge cases need to be taken into account (i.e. 7 bits doesn't fit, discard probability), which gives me a bit of a headache. :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Andrex answer is plain wrong as it counts some combinations several times.

For example consider the case `N=3`, `X=1`. Then the combination `101` happens only `1/2^3` times but the border calculation counts it two times: one as the sequence starting with `10` and another time as the sequence ending with `01`.

His calculations gives a `(1+4)/8` probability whereas there are only `4` unique sequences that have at least a single contiguous `1` (as opposed to cases such as `011`):

```
001
010
100
101
```

and so the probability is `4/8`.

To count the number of unique sequences you need to account for sequences that can appear multiple times. As long as `X` is smaller than `N/2` this will happens. Not sure how you can count them tho.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: I tried to reduce this to the answering part. But it seems all comment. If you intend part of this to actually answer the question please [edit] to rephrase according to [answer]. If all you intend to do it dissect an existing answer please wait for your commenting privilege and delete this non-answer now.

Comment: "there are only 4 unique sequences that have a single 1:" and you list `101` among them. That confuses me.

Comment: "That confuses me." I've edited my answer to make this part clearer.

Comment: I see. Now please edit again to make this an answer instead of a comment on an existing answer. For that it should answer and explain and leave the decision on whether it or the other answer is correct to the voters. I.e. please say "The answer is ... because ... ." And skip any "what I write is correct, the others not". You can vote on the other answer if you like.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer. I believe letting Andrex response as the accepted answer is confusing as it is plain wrong as demonstrated by my response.

Comment: You cannot change the accepted answer. I cannot. Nobody can - with one exception, the author of the question. You can only write an answer according to [answer] which is so convincingly correct that everybody understands. Writing "my answer is correct, the accepted one is incorrect" does not really help with the credibility of your answer.

Comment: This will be my last comment as this is obviously going nowhere. I didn't write "my answer is correct, the accepted one is incorrect". I wrote a **proof** that Andrex answer is incorrect. I don't think I can give something more convincing than a counter example.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30725821)